# From UNIX shell, how to find all files containing a specific string, then print the 4th line of each file?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, sed, grep

I want to find all files within the current directory that contain a given string, then print just the 4th line of each file.

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail? But basically `grep -Frl string . | xargs -n 1 sed -n 4p`

Comment: I tried:

`grep 'mystring' * -r | sed -n 4p`

THANK YOU Yours worked perfectly and fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From other user:

`grep -Frl string . | xargs -n 1 sed -n 4p`

Answer (score 2):

```
grep --null -l "$yourstring" * | # List all the files containing your string
  xargs -0 sed -n '4p;q' # Print the fourth line of said files.
```

Different editions of grep have slightly different incantations of `--null`, but it's usually there in some form. Read your manpage for details.

Update: I believe one of the null file list incantations of grep is a reasonable solution that will cover the vast majority of real-world use cases, but to be entirely portable, if your version of `grep` does not support any null output it is not perfectly safe to use it with `xargs`, so you must resort to `find`.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -q "$yourstring" {} \; -exec sed -n '4p;q' {} +
```

Because `find` arguments can almost all be used as predicates, the `-exec grep -q…` part filters the files that are eventually fed to `sed` down to only those that contain the required string.

Comment: +1 but note that this null stuff is a GNU extension and not entirely portable.

Comment: @tripleee it's not *just* a GNU extension. It exists in BSD `grep` as well. That is not to say it's perfectly standard, but as I said in my answer, it's often there in some form or another. I'll update my answer with a more portable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to the below GNU find command,

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -l 'yourstring' {} \; | xargs -I {} awk 'NR==4{print; exit}' {}
```

It finds all the files in the current directory which contains specific string, and prints the line number 4 present in each file.

Comment: This would recurse to more than the current directory.

Comment: this one times out on me

Comment: You could write this `find … -exec grep -q 'yourstring' {} \; -exec awk 'NR==4' {} +`. Also `awk 'NR==4{print;exit;}'` would let awk exit after printing the fourth line.

Comment: @kojiro thanks for your note. BUt without grep `l`, how can i get the file-name.

Comment: @AvinashRaj `-exec` results can also be used as predicates in `find`. Since `grep -q` will return essentially "true" or "false" when a line matches, the *next* `-exec` statement will execute or not depending on the result of `grep`. `find` will supply the filenames that apply.

Answer (score 0):

This for loop should work:

```
while read -d '' -r file; do
    echo -n "$file: "
    sed '4q;d' "$file"
done < <(grep --null -l "some-text" *.txt)
```

Comment: What if some files have newlines in their names?